# Powershell - Move files 1 folder deeper

Tags: powershell, move, subdirectory

I'm looking to move a large set of pdf files one folder deeper.

The current file structure is:
`[Reference Code]\[file].pdf`
and i'm looking to move the files to:
`[Reference Code]\April 18\[file].pdf`

if i recall correctly this could be done in linux with `mv */*.pdf */April 18/*.pdf` but a solution for windows seems to be a bit more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rootPath = "C:\"
$moveTo = "C:\April 18"

foreach ($pdfFile in (Get-ChildItem $rootPath | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".pdf"}))
{
    Move-Item -Path $pdfFile.FullName -Destination "$moveTo\$($pdfFile.Name)"
}
```

Like this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that worked really nicely and gave a good example for me to build off

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
$rootDir = "Reference Code"

Get-ChildItem -Path "$rootDir\*.pdf" -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination "$rootDir\April 18\$($_.Name)"
    }
```

Note that this will fail if folder `April 18` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the option, i should have specified that i was looking for the script to create the folder, but this gives me a nice example to build from